# How can I get a list of cipher suites available in java 11?

Tags: java, ssl

I'm debugging an SSL problem and trying find how Java knows what cipher suites are supported.

**How can I get a list of the cipher suites that are supported by TLSv1.2 in Java 11?**

**Is there Java code I could write to list the cipher suites available?**

### Searching for answers:

I found that `openssl` can list several.

```
openssl ciphers -V | head
          0xC0,0x30 - ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
          0xC0,0x2C - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
          0xC0,0x28 - ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
          0xC0,0x24 - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
          0xC0,0x14 - ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
          0xC0,0x0A - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
          0x00,0xA5 - DH-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
          0x00,0xA3 - DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
          0x00,0xA1 - DH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
          0x00,0x9F - DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SSLSocketFactory f = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket secureSocket = (SSLSocket) f.createSocket();
stream(secureSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

p.s.
Also there is this cool link from mozilla that recommend based on the webserver: https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=tomcat&version=9.0.30&config=intermediate&guideline=5.6

Comment: On the last line of your sample code, I got a syntax error and changed it to get it to compile.

Answer (score 1):

The SO question [Which Cipher Suites Algorithm Are Supported in Jdk11 and Which One is Best to Use with TLSv1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56286934/which-cipher-suites-algorithm-are-supported-in-jdk11-and-which-one-is-best-to-us) has the answer buried in details of answering a related question.

The link is:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#jsse-cipher-suite-names

The table is very large so it is not reproduced below.